# IE9 not rendering spanned columns correctly with colgroup

Tags: html, html-table, col

I have a grid that is divided into three tables; header, content, and footer. The colgroup is just copied to the other tables via JavaScript. The footer is supposed to only have two columns which are spanned.

```
<table>
    <colgroup>
        <col width="50px" />
        <col width="100px" />
        <col width="200px" />
        <col width="50px" />
        <col width="50px" />
        <col width="50px" />
        <col width="50px" />
        <col width="50px" />
        <col width="50px" />
        <col width="50px" />
    </colgroup>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="7" class="text-align-right">colspan 7</td>
            <td colspan="3">colspan 3</td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

In Chrome and Firefox, the table looks like this:
[image]

But in IE9 it looks like this:
[image]

How could I align the footer columns for IE9?

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/E5BZT/1/)

Comment: A question should contain sufficient code to actually reproduce the problem, and the problem should be described concretely; “not working” is not as problem description. The problem does not seem to be reproducible on IE 10 in IE 9 mode. And the markup is invalid, violation HTML table model (validate as HTML5 to see how).

Comment: I tried validating the updated jsfiddle. Does that mean that the number of <col> tags be equal to the number of <td> tags?